# How to copy data from one column to a new column based on price range in R?

Tags: mysql, r, dataframe, for-loop, datatable

**Hello, i have a dataset on shoes prices from amazon which look like this**

| Brand | Available | Price | color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Nike | Yes | $50 | Red |
| Nike | Yes | $40 - $50 | RED |
| Adidas | Yes | $46 - $90 | White |
| Puma | Yes | NAN | White |

My task is, if there are two prices like for second and third row then create a new row in table and put the second price, and if price is NAN then delete that column too.

I am new to R language and trying to solve this from 3 days, my task is to show mean prices of different brands in R with graphs like scatter plot graph, i am expecting the output like this:

| Brand | Available | Price | color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Nike | Yes | $50 | Red |
| Nike | Yes | $40 | RED |
| Adidas | Yes | $46 | White |
| Nike | Yes | $50 | RED |
| Adidas | Yes | $90 | White |

i tried different code but nothing is working can someone please help me with this.

This is my [dataset](https://data.world/crawlfeeds/amazon-uk-shoes-dataset/workspace/file?filename=amazon_uk_shoes_dataset.json)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could use `separate_rows` with the `-` separator and omit NAs:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  separate_rows(Price, sep=" - ") %>% 
  na.omit()
```

```
  Brand  Available Price color
  <chr>  <chr>     <chr> <chr>
1 Nike   Yes       $50   Red  
2 Nike   Yes       $40   RED  
3 Nike   Yes       $50   RED  
4 Adidas Yes       $46   White
5 Adidas Yes       $90   White
```

Comment: thanks mate it create a new row, just another question my second task is to show mean prices of different brands in a scatter plot and box plot and save that visualization in a PDF, can you please suggest any idea or code for that.

Comment: This is no problem. Best is to open a new question by providing a sample data. I would suggest a ggplot after some data wrangling.

Comment: For example: `df %>% 
  mutate(Price_1 = parse_number(Price)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Brand, y=Price_1)) +
  geom_boxplot()`